# SQL Query notification from C++ ADO

Tags: c++, sql-server, ado

I have two apps that need to receive notifications when data in a table changes. One .NET and the other C++ MFC. I decided to go with SQL Query Notifications.

I have built a proof of concept for the .NET app with SqlDependency class, but am struggling with the MFC version.

I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx, but am not proficient enough with c++ to make sense of this.

Has anyone done this before? If so, could you please post some sample code or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see example code for C++ anywhere.

Rather than write and debug this (complex) event detection code twice, it would be possible (and preferable imo) to implement it in C#, and then expose the required function to your MFC app via COM interop.  See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ManagedCOM.aspx) for a brief overview.

Comment: I went with sending structs over TCP from C# window service to the C++ app.